# How to set Jtable name of columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have this piece of code

```
String [] titles = {"حذف", "شماره درس","گروه","واحد","نام","تعداد ثبت نامی","نام استاد","زمان امتحان","زمان کلاس","وضعیت پیشنیازی ها","محدودیت"};
    String[][] value = new String[1][11];
    JTable table = new JTable(value, titles);
    table.setBounds(800,450,1100,80);
    table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2, true));
    table.setRowHeight(40);
    table.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    table.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    mainPanel.add(table);
```

but it doesn't work :/
[image]
It displays this while columns should have name :/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainPanel.add(table);
```

The table header is only displayed automatically when you add the table to a scroll pane.

The code should be:

```
//mainPanel.add(table);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
mainPanel.add( scrollPane );
```